# Parse JSON to Google Charts

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-visualization

I'm looking for a way to parse my json to a simple js line chart. I tried ChartJS but had no success, than I tried Google Charts.

The problem is that I have a long JSON to parse and couldn't figure out a way to filter it and parse to Google Chart.

I'd like to filter the JSON and get the values and dates for only one node (for example: get the values for `ABEV3` in the JSON below).

The JSON:

```
{
    "RAIL3": {
        "2021-02-12": "20.18",
        "2021-02-11": "19.81",
        "2021-02-10": "20.13",
        "2021-02-09": "20.85",
        "2021-02-08": "21.35",
        "2021-02-05": "21.35",
        "2021-02-04": "21.50",
        "2021-02-03": "21.70",
        "2021-02-02": "20.77",
        "2021-02-01": "21.10",
        "2021-01-29": "20.30",
        "2021-01-28": "20.92",
        "2021-01-27": "20.74",
        "2021-01-26": "20.67",
        "2021-01-22": "20.85",
        "2021-01-21": "20.89",
        "2021-01-20": "21.03",
        "2021-01-19": "21.10",
        "2021-01-18": "20.92",
        "2021-01-15": "21.21",
        "2021-01-14": "20.74"
    },
    "ABEV3": {
        "2021-02-12": "14.79",
        "2021-02-11": "14.95",
        "2021-02-10": "15.01",
        "2021-02-09": "14.96",
        "2021-02-08": "14.94",
        "2021-02-05": "15.52",
        "2021-02-04": "15.60",
        "2021-02-03": "15.68",
        "2021-02-02": "15.61",
        "2021-02-01": "15.60",
        "2021-01-29": "15.11",
        "2021-01-28": "15.54",
        "2021-01-27": "15.39",
        "2021-01-26": "15.40",
        "2021-01-22": "15.15",
        "2021-01-21": "15.61",
        "2021-01-20": "16.02",
        "2021-01-19": "16.27",
        "2021-01-18": "16.22",
        "2021-01-15": "15.95",
        "2021-01-14": "16.26"
    },
    "BBAS3": {
        "2021-02-12": "33.75",
        "2021-02-11": "33.94",
        "2021-02-10": "33.81",
        "2021-02-09": "34.28",
        "2021-02-08": "33.87",
        "2021-02-05": "33.96",
        "2021-02-04": "34.19",
        "2021-02-03": "34.33",
        "2021-02-02": "34.06",
        "2021-02-01": "34.29",
        "2021-01-29": "33.86",
        "2021-01-28": "34.54",
        "2021-01-27": "33.59",
        "2021-01-26": "32.79",
        "2021-01-22": "33.69",
        "2021-01-21": "34.18",
        "2021-01-20": "34.53",
        "2021-01-19": "35.32",
        "2021-01-18": "35.93",
        "2021-01-15": "36.30",
        "2021-01-14": "37.46"
    }
}
```

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      
    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "jsonfile.json",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
          
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 400});
    }

    </script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `responseJSON` can be used instead of `responseText`.
- If you want to use the values of `ABEV3`, you can retrieve the values of `ABEV3` with `jsonData.ABEV3`.
- And, I think that it is required to be modified the type of each value from the string to the number.
- Please modify `google.visualization.Line` to `google.visualization.LineChart`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `drawChart()` as follows.

```
function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "jsonfile.json",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
  }).responseJSON;
  
  var key = "ABEV3";  // Please set the key you want to use.
  var ar = Object.entries(jsonData[key]).map(([a, b]) => [a, Number(b)]);
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'value');
  data.addRows(ar);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 400});
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your `url: "jsonfile.json",` can return the JSON data in your question. Please be careful this.
- This modified script is a simple modification using your script. So, please modify it for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Line Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Comment: @grc Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, is there a way to convert the hAxis to date instead of string? Is there a simpler way than making a loop through JSON file and adding it one by one using "new Date" function? Thanks!

Comment: @grc I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I totally understand and thanks for the tips (it's great for the sustainability of the stackoverflow community). I have already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231812/format-haxis-to-date-google-chart/

Comment: @grc Thank you for your quick reply. When I saw your new question, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.