# Format hAxis to date - Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, google-visualization

I have the following code and json file. I'd like to change the hAxis to date, but nothing seems to work. I've tried `format:'MMM-dd'` in data options, but it doesn't work. Is it something about the json structure that Im parsing?

There are some array structure in Google Chart using `new Date(Y, m, d)`. Do I have to use that? Or is there a way to adapt my script to date format? Thanks!

JSON file:

```
{
    "RAIL3": {
        "2021-02-12": "20.18",
        "2021-02-11": "19.81",
        "2021-02-10": "20.13",
        "2021-02-09": "20.85",
        "2021-02-08": "21.35",
        "2021-02-05": "21.35",
        "2021-02-04": "21.50",
        "2021-02-03": "21.70",
        "2021-02-02": "20.77",
        "2021-02-01": "21.10",
        "2021-01-29": "20.30",
        "2021-01-28": "20.92",
        "2021-01-27": "20.74",
        "2021-01-26": "20.67",
        "2021-01-22": "20.85",
        "2021-01-21": "20.89",
        "2021-01-20": "21.03",
        "2021-01-19": "21.10",
        "2021-01-18": "20.92",
        "2021-01-15": "21.21",
        "2021-01-14": "20.74"
    },
    "ABEV3": {
        "2021-02-12": "14.79",
        "2021-02-11": "14.95",
        "2021-02-10": "15.01",
        "2021-02-09": "14.96",
        "2021-02-08": "14.94",
        "2021-02-05": "15.52",
        "2021-02-04": "15.60",
        "2021-02-03": "15.68",
        "2021-02-02": "15.61",
        "2021-02-01": "15.60",
        "2021-01-29": "15.11",
        "2021-01-28": "15.54",
        "2021-01-27": "15.39",
        "2021-01-26": "15.40",
        "2021-01-22": "15.15",
        "2021-01-21": "15.61",
        "2021-01-20": "16.02",
        "2021-01-19": "16.27",
        "2021-01-18": "16.22",
        "2021-01-15": "15.95",
        "2021-01-14": "16.26"
    },
    "BBAS3": {
        "2021-02-12": "33.75",
        "2021-02-11": "33.94",
        "2021-02-10": "33.81",
        "2021-02-09": "34.28",
        "2021-02-08": "33.87",
        "2021-02-05": "33.96",
        "2021-02-04": "34.19",
        "2021-02-03": "34.33",
        "2021-02-02": "34.06",
        "2021-02-01": "34.29",
        "2021-01-29": "33.86",
        "2021-01-28": "34.54",
        "2021-01-27": "33.59",
        "2021-01-26": "32.79",
        "2021-01-22": "33.69",
        "2021-01-21": "34.18",
        "2021-01-20": "34.53",
        "2021-01-19": "35.32",
        "2021-01-18": "35.93",
        "2021-01-15": "36.30",
        "2021-01-14": "37.46"
    }
}
```

Html+JS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Google Chart test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      
    
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      

    
    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "json_file.json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
      }).responseJSON;
      
      var key = "ABEV3";
      var ar = Object.entries(jsonData[key]).map(([a, b]) => [(a), Number(b)]);
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      
      var options = {
               
        legend: 'none',
        colors: ['#00FF00'],       
        smoothLine: true,
               width: 400, 
               height: 400,
               'chartArea': {
                    'backgroundColor': {
                        'fill': 'transparent'  
                    }
                },
                vAxis: {
                    baselineColor: 'transparent',  
                    gridlines: {
                        color: '#f3f3f3',
                    }
                },
                hAxis: {
                  format: 'dd/MM/yy'
                },
                
     };
      data.addColumn('string', 'date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'value');

      data.addRows(ar);
      data.sort([{column: 0}]);
      
      var container =  document.getElementById('chart_div')
      var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);

      chart.draw(data, options);
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it that you want to format the date "MMM-dd"? (as what have above works fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the formatter to work you need to ensure your date values are Date objects and the column type is "date".

Example: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/c4d97e495fe4ce259dadc9ccb0451c03

At the moment, you are using "strings".

See this line:

```
var ar = Object.entries(jsonData[key]).map(([a, b]) => [new Date(a), Number(b)]);
```

And also see this line:

```
data.addColumn('date', 'date');
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Many thanks. I tried before the `new Date(a)` trick alone and it didn't work. Then I tried changing the format to `date` and not setting the `new Date(a)`. Now I know that I should have set both together to work. Thanks once again. Cheers!

Comment: Btw, this also corrects the fact that vAxis baseline was not showing up. Now I have full grid with vertical and horizontal lines, including their baselines.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Found myself in the exact same scenario once as the docs didn’t seem clear on this. Cheers